# View contact file while entering contribution batch?

Tags: civicontribute, contacts, profile, duplicate-contacts, batches

Is it possible to view/open in a new window a contact's profile while entering a contribution batch?

I know that a contact's email address will appear in the dropdown with the contact's name. However, it's tricky to choose between two contacts with identical names (e.g., Joe Smith and Joe Smith) because (a) not all our contacts have email addresses and (b) over time there has been incomplete data entry for one reason or another.